# How to get the Exchange server calendar items to bind it into radscheduler

Tags: radscheduler, exchange-server-2010

I am working on radscheduler.

I want to bind the exchange server calendar items in to radscheduler, Please send any article or sample program about how to get the calendar Items from Exchange Server, it's very useful for me, kindly send it to me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is very late for you, but currently I'm using the DLL's provided on this website [click here for Independentsoft](http://www.independentsoft.de)

It is possible to connect to exchange etc. You can find a way to store them in the database if you like, or create an array of Appointments etc.

Good luck!